# Residual bubble plot of krige.cv function dataframe

Tags: kriging, spatial-analysis, cross-validation

I want to plot a bubble plot of residuals from the krige.cv function with the bubble function.

However I get an error:

```
Error in as(obj, "SpatialPointsDataFrame") : 
no method or default for coercing “data.frame” to “SpatialPointsDataFrame”
```

I'd like to understand this error in detail and possible tipps or solutions. I understand that I need to convert my results, but I don't know how.

Here is my code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(phylin)
library(viridis)
library(gstat)
library(automap)  
library(patchwork)
library(raster)
library(fields)
library(dplyr)

norf_df <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\49151\\Desktop\\ba_study_areas\\norv_343.csv",
                      header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, sep = ",")

max(norf_df['Z'])
min(norf_df['Z'])

hist(norf_df$Z, breaks = 10, xlab = "displacment in mm/year", main = "Histogram of displacment")

sd(norf_df$Z)

## make sf object of data
crs = st_crs("EPSG:32632")

norf_df_sf <- st_as_sf(norf_df, coords = c("X", "Y"), crs = "OGC:CRS84")%>%
  st_transform(crs)

##grid to be interpolated

grd_100_sf <- norf_df_sf %>%
  st_make_grid(
    cellsize = c(50, 50),
    what = "centers"
  ) %>%
  st_as_sf() %>%
  cbind(., st_coordinates(.))

##get the coordinates and values of Original Data

data <- norf_df_sf %>%
  cbind(., st_coordinates(.)) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  dplyr::select(X,Y,Z)

##get coords of grid

grd <- grd_100_sf %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  dplyr::select(X,Y)

v_mod_OK <- automap::autofitVariogram(Z~1, as(norf_df_sf, "Spatial"))$var_model

grd_100_sf_sp <- as(grd_100_sf, "Spatial")
gridded(grd_100_sf_sp) <- TRUE 
grd_100_sf_sp <- as(grd_100_sf_sp, "SpatialPixels") 
SK_cv <- krige.cv(
  Z~1,                       
  beta = mean(norf_df$Z),
  as(norf_df_sf, "Spatial"), 
  grd_100_sf_sp,                
  model = v_mod_OK,
  nfold = 100
)

SK_cv_df <- as.data.frame(SK_cv)

p1<-bubble(SK_cv_df,zcol="residual",main="Cross Validation Residual LogPCB by Sph Model",pch=1)
```

Please ignore the value for nfold, as this is just a placeholder, so that the computation time is short.

here is my data: https://ufile.io/deou5t91

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this discussion will be useful on how to convert your data: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32583606/create-spatialpointsdataframe

This is what it could look like with your script:

```
SK_cv_pt_df <- SK_cv_df
coordinates(SK_cv_pt_df) <- ~coords.x1+coords.x2

p1<-bubble(SK_cv_pt_df,zcol="residual",main="Cross Validation Residual LogPCB by Sph Model",pch=1)
show(p1)
```